# iOS 5 and UIViewController presentViewController - is it now possible to change the size of the modal controller without a hack?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Back then with `presentModalViewController` it was possible to adjust the size of the modal controller **after** it had been presented. This was a hack but it worked, although it caused problems with animations.
I'm wondering if there is an official way now with iOS 5 to allow adjustments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it like this and it works fine.

```
[controller setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

[controller.view.superview setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
[controller.view.superview setFrame:CGRectMake(64, 64, 896, 640)];
```

Comment: Is it working flawless with rotation? Is the resizing visible?

Comment: I only support Landscape left and Landscape Right and it works perfectly with that rotation. I haven't tried it in a project thats portrait. But I'd assume you could handle for it in willRotate

Comment: Oh well, that's then basically the same kludge as it used to be. But if there is nothing new, why not stick with it. Thx.

Comment: Im working on a solution that can be contained in the viewController being presenting rather than the controller presenting it. But there are LOTS of caveats.

Comment: This is pretty interesting.

Comment: Yea its a bit of a hack but it definitely works. I have it in several places in several shipping apps. Also I've found a way to encapsulate it in the viewController itself. You can place the last two important lines into `-viewWillLayoutSubviews`